# Python user define magic method

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, oop, built-in

How can I implement `__radd__` in my fraction class?

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,num,den):
        self.num = num
        self.den = den
    def __add__(self,other):
        num = self.num * other.den + other.num * self.den
        den = self.den * other.den
        common = self.gcf(num,den)
        return Fraction(num/common , den/common)

    def __iadd__(self,other):
        self.num = self.num * other.den + other.num * self.den
        self.den = self.den * other.den
        common = self.gcf(self.num,self.den)
        self.num = self.num/common
        self.den = self.den/common
        return self

    def __radd__(self,other):
        pass
```

Comment: The same exact way you would implement `__add__`, but with the arguments switched around. If that isn't satisfactory, your `__add__` is also messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your implementation you are always adding only fractions there is no need to implement `__radd__`, because you already have `__add__`.

[object.__radd__](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types.

But in case you wanted it anyway, you can just swap the parameters since addition is commutative.

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    return other + self
```